# mounting partition with forgotten password

Tags: mount

I cannt mountig to another part of my hdd which is windows10 and i lost my windows password....when i try to mount it to get my pictures which are saved there... the messege i get is:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/fareidon/Windows8_OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda5" "/media/fareidon/Windows8_OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operasjonen er ikke tillatt
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

what shall i do it without the windows password..thanks for helping

---

i tried this comand
sudo mount -t ntfs -o uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda5 /media/fareidon/Windows8_OS

but its ask me the password which i said i forgot it!

and tried this comand to:

mount  /dev/sda5 /media/fareidon/windows8_os -o ro

the answer i get :

mount: only root can use"--options"optios

somebody can help,still i cannt mount,the big problem is the windows password!!
when i comand any command,it ask me the password of windows which i forgott!!

Comment: Try `ntfsfix` mentioned in second answer

Comment: You can properly shut down windows without logging in. That should eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to force mount it. And the command is already given... use it with sudo...

Final command :

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda5 /media/fareidon/Windows8_OS
```

You will need to enter your password, it wont be seen...
Try it out...

Comment: The problem is that the file system is not clean, so it needs to be mounted read-only by adding `ro` to the options list.

Comment: @antiguru : No, you can mount it without ro. I have done that before. If you gave downvote for that, remove it.

Comment: i have tried to add ro  to the option,but not suceses..i jaust want to say i am new in ubuntu....can you expalne please the exact steps and commands ican do ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message states the solution: Mount the volume read-only. As root, run something like the following command:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /media/fareidon/Windows8_OS -o ro
```

Note that the mount target (`/media/fareidon/Windows8_OS`) needs to exist.